# How to reorder geom_point ggplot2 plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know this type of question has been asked many times before, but I just can't get any of the solutions to work for me.

Basically I'm trying to reorder a plot using ggplot2's geom_point. Here's an example of my data frame:

```
> df

> Title: x1:x2, x2:x1, z:x1, x1:z
> 
> value: 64, 34, 21, 6
```

What I'm trying to do is reorder them by `value`, from lowest to highest, using ggplot.

`Title` is a `factor` and `value` is `num`.

Here's the code I was using just to plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, y=Title)) +
  geom_point(color="blue", size=4)
```

I've been trying to follow other examples where they say to order using something like:

```
df$value <- df[order(df$value), ]
```

but after reordering `df$value`, ggplot overwrites the order. Effectively the order I'm trying to plot would something like this:

> Title: x1:z, z:x1, x2:x1, x1:x2
>
> value: 6, 21, 34, 64

any suggestions as to how I'd fix this?

Comment: re-order how? Can you add the desired output? Or give a little more explanation? Also, what class is each of your variables? Is the value numeric or a factor? Yousay you want to re-order by value, but your order statement uses Title...I'm a little confused

Comment: Apologies, it's late and it was poorly asked. I've re-editted the question for clarity

Comment: Can you provide `dput` of your dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to use `reorder` within `ggplot`. I think `Title` should be your x-axis variable.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Title, value), value)) + 
  geom_point()
```

You could also look at `?forcats::fct_reorder`.

Comment: This worked and a simple fix, thanks for your answer